# How to combine two query to makes multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to combine 2 query to make one result like this

```
Sandi | schemaid | value | Sandi | schemaid | value
100   | 2883     | 12324 | 200   | 2886     | 3456
120   | 2882     | 435   | 220   | 2887     | 555 
130   | 2881     | 3456  | 230   | 2888     | 333
```

and the query's are:

```
select y.Sandi , y.schemaid,y.value from tbl_schema y
where y.idx=1

select y.Sandi , y.schemaid,y.value from tbl_schema y
where y.idx=2
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the separate `idx` data to appear in columns and not rows, then you could use include a `row_number()` and join the separate queries on the row_number, similar to this:

```
select
  q1.Sandi q1_Sandi,
  q1.schemaid q1_schemaid,
  q1.value q1_value,
  q2.sandi q2_Sandi,
  q2.schemaid q2_schema_id,
  q2.value q2_value
from
(
  select sandi, schemaid, value,
    row_number() over (order by sandi) rn
  from tbl_schema
  where idx = 1
) q1
full outer join
(
  select sandi, schemaid, value,
    row_number() over (order by sandi) rn
  from tbl_schema
  where idx = 2
) q2
  on q1.rn = q2.rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fd3f/4)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using same table (tbl_schema) in both queries, *`for given ids (idx)`* I think you could use a `full outer join` as below:

```
select y.Sandi, y.schemaid, y.value, x.Sandi_, x.schemaid_, x.value_  
from tbl_schema y full outer join tbl_schema x
       on y.idx + 1 = x.idx
where y.idx = 1 and x.idx = 2
```